# outlook 2010 small images

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

i have a html email layout. Layout render good in most clients but in Outlook 2010 the images are loaded small but after clicking on display in new window the images resize to it's normall size. Do anyone know what is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. HTML emails are a complex subject, so it's hard to tell you the cause without having a reproducible example.

Comment: hi, there is my template: https://pastebin.com/iUNWBnRD